# What's the problem with this code for a resolvent calculator?

Tags: c++, if-statement, calculator, quadratic

This code is for a resolvent calculator (the variables are in Spanish, but I think you will have no problem reading it).  I don't know why this code doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a, b, c, raiz, r, resultado1, resultado2;

    cout<<"Determine el valor de A: "; cin>> a; cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Determine el valor de B: "; cin>> b; cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Determine el valor de C: "; cin>> c; cout<<"\n";

    raiz = pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c);
    r = sqrt(raiz);

    if (raiz > 0) {
        resultado1 = ((b * -1) + r) / (2 * a);
        resultado2 = ((b * -1) - r) / (2 * a);

        cout<<"El valor de X1 es: "<<resultado1<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"El valor de X2 es: "<<resultado2<<endl<<endl;

    }

    if (raiz < 0) {
        cout<<"La raiz posee un valor negativo, por lo que no podra resolverse. El valor negativo dentro 
               de la raiz es "<<raiz;
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to describe *precisely* how your program doesn't work. Show an example of input, output, and expected output.

Comment: In what way exactly does it "not work"?  You need to be more specific.

Comment: If you're just learning C++, that's great, but avoid `using namespace std`. The `std::` prefix might seem annoying, but it serves an important purpose, namely separating Standard Library code from your own.

Comment: Tip: Instead of declaring a heap of variables all at once, declare them individually *as necessary*, in the context in which they're used. As in: `double r = sqrt(raiz)`.

Comment: Tactical note: Compilers are getting smarter and smarter and some know this trick, but `pow(b,2)` is usually less effective than `b*b`. a simple multiplication may be faster and because `pow` operates on floating point numbers and floating point numbers are imprecise, there may be some damage done in the computation that becomes really noticeable when converting back to integers.

Comment: You could replace `getch()` with `std::cin.ignore(1000000, '\n');` and remove the #include <conio.h>`

Answer (score 2):

Even if `a`, `b` and `c` are `int`s, the results for `r`, `resultado1` and `resultado2` don't have to be. They should be defined as `double`s:

```
double r, resultado1, resultado2;
```

Comment: Thanks to you and everyone!!